# Trouble with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

The idea for this function is to take a file as input. this file contains politicians with their respective parties.  independent is 1, republican is 2, democrat is 3, and not known is 4.  what has to be returned is the number of times each party is represented.

the file has independent 6, republican 16, democrat 22, and not known 6.
the output should look like this.

Independent 6

Republican 16

Democrat 22

Not Known 6

but what i have is

4 6

3 22

2 16

1 6

and I'm not sure how to change the number representing the parties to the names of the actual parties.

```
def polDict(s1):
        infile=open(s1,'r')
        content=infile.read()
        counters={}
        party='1234'
        wordList = content.split()
        for i in wordList:
            if i in party:
                if i in counters:
                    counters[i]+=1
                else:
                    counters[i]=1
        for i in counters:              

            print('{:2} {}'.format(i,counters[i]))
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you please restructure your question? What does the data look like in your file. Also, restructure your expected output in an actual dictionary, formatted in this question. Finally, please explain what exactly is going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information about how your file looks like; that being said, with the limited information given, if I understood your code correctly, what you need to do is define a dictionary with the party names and their respective numbers and then edit your print statement to print the party name respective to `i` instead of `i` itself:

```
def polDict(s1):
    infile=open(s1,'r')
    content=infile.read()
    counters={}
    party='1234'
    party_names = {1:'Independent', 2:'Republican', 3:'Democrat', 4:'Not known'}
    wordList = content.split()
    for i in wordList:
        if i in party:
            if i in counters:
                counters[i]+=1
            else:
                counters[i]=1
    for i in counters:              
        print('{:2} {}'.format(party_names[i], counters[i]))
```

Comment: the contents of the file looks like this  Hillary Clinton 3
Bill Clinton 3
Jeb Bush 2
Ted Cruz 2
Donald Trump 4
Bernie Sanders 1
Barak Obama 3
Chris Christy 2
Hillary Clinton 3
Bill Clinton 3
Jeb Bush 2
Ted Cruz 2
Donald Trump 4
Bernie Sanders 1
Barak Obama 3
Chris Christy 2
Hillary Clinton 3
Bill Clinton 3
Jeb Bush 2
Ted Cruz 2
Donald Trump 4
Bernie Sanders 1 but they're all on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `open()` which is one of many reasons to use the `with` block. Anyways, I'm assuming this is the style of the input file:

> Clinton 3
>   Cruz 2 
>   Sanders 3
>   Trump 2
>   Dutter 1

And you want the output to be:

> Republican 2
>   Democratic 2
>   Independent 1

If this is not correct, then this function should be changed to fit exactly what you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def getCandidates(infile):
    parties = {1: "Independent", 2: "Republican", 3: "Democratic", 4: "Unknown"}
    candidates = defaultdict(int)
    with open(infile, "r") as fin:
        for line in fin:  # assuming only 2 columns and the last column is the number
            candidates[parties[int(line.split()[-1])]] += 1
    for party, count in candidates.items():  #.iteritems() in python 2.7
        print("{} {}".format(party, count))

getCandidates("test.txt")
```